# GLSL, reading wrong value inside a fragment shader for a bounded depth texture

Tags: jogl, fragment-shader, opengl-3, depth-buffer

I am applying a slightly modified version of the classic depth peeling algorithm, basically I am rendering all the opaque objects first and then I use that depth as minimum depth, because since they are opaque, it doesnt make sense to not discard fragment deeper than them.

I first tested it on a small [test case](https://github.com/elect86/depthPeeling/tree/master/DepthPeeling/src/depthPeeling/dpGl3OfficialOpaque) and it works flawless.

Now I am applying this algorithm to my main application, but for some unknown reasons, it doesnt work and I am going crazy, the main problem is that I keep reading the value 0 for the opaque depth texture bounded in the fragment shader of the next stage

To sum up, this is the fbo for the opaque stuff:

```
opaqueDepthTexture = new int[1];
opaqueColorTexture = new int[1];
opaqueFbo = new int[1];

gl3.glGenTextures(1, opaqueDepthTexture, 0);
gl3.glGenTextures(1, opaqueColorTexture, 0);
gl3.glGenFramebuffers(1, opaqueFbo, 0);

gl3.glBindTexture(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, opaqueDepthTexture[0]);

gl3.glTexImage2D(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL3.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, width, height, 0,
        GL3.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL3.GL_FLOAT, null);
gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);

gl3.glBindTexture(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, opaqueColorTexture[0]);

gl3.glTexImage2D(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL3.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
        GL3.GL_RGBA, GL3.GL_FLOAT, null);
gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);

gl3.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, opaqueFbo[0]);

gl3.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL3.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,
        opaqueDepthTexture[0], 0);
gl3.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL3.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE,
        opaqueColorTexture[0], 0);
checkBindedFrameBuffer(gl3);
```

Here I *just* clear the depth (default to 1), I even commented out the opaque rendering:

```
        /**
         * (1) Initialize Opaque FBO.
         */
        gl3.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, opaqueFbo[0]);
        gl3.glDrawBuffer(GL3.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

        gl3.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        gl3.glClear(GL3.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL3.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl3.glEnable(GL3.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        dpOpaque.bind(gl3);
        {
//            EC_Graph.instance.getRoot().renderDpOpaque(gl3, dpOpaque, new MatrixStack(), properties);
        }
        dpOpaque.unbind(gl3);
```

And I have a double confirmation from this

```
FloatBuffer fb = FloatBuffer.allocate(1 * GLBuffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT);
gl3.glReadPixels(width / 2, height / 2, 1, 1, GL3.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL3.GL_FLOAT, fb);
System.out.println("opaque fb.get(0) " + fb.get(0));
```

If I change the clearDepth to 0.9 for example, I get 0.9, so this is ok.

Now I initialize the minimum depth buffer, by rendering all the geometry having alpha < 1 and I bind the previous depth texture, the one used in the opaque rendering, to the

```
uniform sampler2D opaqueDepthTexture;
```

I temporarily switched the rendering of this passage to the default framebuffer

```
        /**
         * (2) Initialize Min Depth Buffer.
         */
        gl3.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        gl3.glDrawBuffer(GL3.GL_BACK);
//        gl3.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, blendFbo[0]);
//        gl3.glDrawBuffer(GL3.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

        gl3.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        gl3.glClear(GL3.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL3.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl3.glEnable(GL3.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        if (cullFace) {

            gl3.glEnable(GL3.GL_CULL_FACE);
        }
        dpInit.bind(gl3);
        {
            gl3.glActiveTexture(GL3.GL_TEXTURE1);
            gl3.glBindTexture(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, opaqueDepthTexture[0]);
            gl3.glUniform1i(dpInit.getOpaqueDepthTextureUL(), 1);
            gl3.glBindSampler(1, sampler[0]);
            {
                EC_Graph.instance.getRoot().renderDpTransparent(gl3, dpInit, new MatrixStack(), properties);
            }
            gl3.glBindTexture(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0);
            gl3.glBindSampler(1, 0);
        }
        dpInit.unbind(gl3);
```

This is the dpInit Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D texture0;
in vec2 oUV;

uniform sampler2D opaqueDepthTexture;
/*
*   Layout {lighting, normal orientation, active, selected}
*/
uniform ivec4 settings;

const vec3 selectionColor = vec3(1, .5, 0);
const vec4 inactiveColor = vec4(.5, .5, .5, .2);

vec4 CalculateLight();

void main()
{
    float opaqueDepth = texture(opaqueDepthTexture, gl_FragCoord.xy).r;
    if(gl_FragCoord.z > opaqueDepth) {        
        //discard;
    }

    vec4 color = (1 - settings.x) * texture(texture0, oUV) + settings.x * CalculateLight();

    if(settings.w == 1) {

        if(settings.z == 1) {

            color = vec4(selectionColor, color.q);

        } else {

            color = vec4(selectionColor, inactiveColor.w);
        }
    } else {

        if(settings.z == 0) {

            color = inactiveColor;
        }
    }
    outputColor = vec4(color.rgb * color.a, 1.0 - color.a);
    outputColor = vec4(.5, 1, 1, 1.0 - color.a);

    if(opaqueDepth == 0)
        outputColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    else
        outputColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
}
```

Ignore the middle, the important is just at the begin, where I read the red component of the previous depth texture and then I compare at the end, and the geometry I obtain is red, this means the value I read in the opaqueDepthTexture is 0...

The question is why?

After the dpInit rendering, if I bind again the opaqueFbo and read the depth, it is always the clearDepth, so 1 as default or .9 if I cleared it with .9, so it works.

The problem is really that I read the wrong value in the dpInit FS from a bound depth texture.. why?

For clarification, this is the sampler:

```
private void initSampler(GL3 gl3) {

    sampler = new int[1];
    gl3.glGenSamplers(1, sampler, 0);

    gl3.glSamplerParameteri(sampler[0], GL3.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL3.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl3.glSamplerParameteri(sampler[0], GL3.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL3.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl3.glSamplerParameteri(sampler[0], GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL3.GL_NEAREST);
    gl3.glSamplerParameteri(sampler[0], GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL3.GL_NEAREST);
}
```

Ps: checking all the components, I see the opaqueDepthTexture has always the following values (0, 0, 0, 1)

Comment: You should use GLBuffers.newDirectFloatBuffer() instead of FloatBuffer.allocate() even though it isn't the culprit in your case. In my humble opinion, you should modify elect86's example step by step to find which change breaks your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god, I found it, in the init FS

```
uniform sampler2D opaqueDepthTexture;
```

should be

```
uniform sampler2DRect opaqueDepthTexture;
```